# Why does logster need a redis connection while building asset:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, discourse, logster

I have a ruby on rails 7 project.

To create my Docker containers, I use the default Dockerfile to create the image while running `rails new`.

The Dockerfile contains the instructions to compile assets:

```
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=`bundle exec rake secret` bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Since I added [Logster](https://github.com/discourse/logster) into my Gemfile. I do have a lot of errors coming from this line because Logster cannot establish a connection with [Redis](https://redis.io/).

For my part, this is the expected behavior because when building a Docker image, none of my services are running.

What can I do prevent the error from being shown or handled?

I did create a dummy Redis service which is added when running this single rake task in my application. This way I do not need a Redis connection and I do not have errors. However, I found my solution too hacky and I want to do it the right way.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for that?
I'm doing something very similar and I don't understand why I need redis when building my image.

Comment: I did not... I am still using a dummy Redis service which is clearly not the right solution.